# Blurry fonts on transform-css

Tags: css, css-transforms

So, I have a dropdown menu, this is my css for the animation on the hover event

```
.secondary_nav {
  display: none;
}

.primary_nav > ul > li:hover {
  perspective: 1000px;
}

primary_nav > ul > li:hover .secondary_nav {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: dropdown 300ms ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes dropdown {
  0% {
   opacity: 0;
   transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateY(30px);
  }
  100% {
   opacity: 1;
   transform: rotateY(0deg) translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

The thing is, the fonts looks so blurry on the li's, I mean, the difference is noticeable (it's not that bad, but it's like the cleartype - for those Windows users - magically switch off), and this happens both on Chrome and Firefox. The submenus of these li's, however, are not affected.

If I take off the transform property everything looks fine.

Anyone knows how to fix it? Not a big deal, but it's so annoying.

Already tried to add **-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;** but it's not working.

Thank you all in advance.

This is the structure of the Html, sorry, I forgot it.

```
<div class="primary_nav"> 
 <ul data-role="primaryNavBar"> 
  <li> 
   <a href="">Example</a> 
   <ul class="secondary_nav">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
   </ul> 
  </li> 
 </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the html ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it. Added on the original post...

Comment: Maybe try added a working code snippet illustrating the issue, Would be much easier to debug.